# How can I improve my solution for implementing the Observer Pattern using Java Generics?

Tags: java, generics, observer-pattern

Unsatisfying Solution for Implementing Observer Pattern Using Java Generics

For educational reasons I wanted to implement the Observer Pattern using Java Generics.
I came up with the following solution:

```
public interface Observer <T extends Observable<?>>
{
    void update(T observable);
}
```

```
public abstract class Observable <T extends Observable<?>>
{
    private final List<Observer<T>> observerList = new ArrayList<>();
    
    
    public void addObserver(Observer<T> observer)
    {
        this.observerList.add(observer);
    }
    
    public void notifyObservers()
    {
        for( Observer<T> observer : this.observerList)
        {
            observer.update(getIdentity());
        }
    }
    
    public abstract T getIdentity();
}
```

Now I can have a class

```
class Data extends Observable<Data>
```

and an Observer

```
class DataObserver implements Observer<Data>
```

What I dislike about this solution:

- the method *getIdentity*
- the usage of a type parameter in the class of the observable

To address these concerns, I came up with a second solution using bounded wildcard parameters:

```
interface Observer<T extends Observable>
{
    void update(T observable);
}
```

```
abstract class Observable
{
    private final List<Observer<? extends Observable>> observerList = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public void addObserver(Observer<? extends Observable> observer)
    {
        this.observerList.add(observer);
    }
    
    public void notifyObservers()
    {
        for(Observer<? extends Observable> observer : this.observerList)
        {
            observer.update(getIdentity());
        }
    }
    
    public abstract <T extends Observable> T getIdentity();
}
```

Now, I no longer have a type parameter in the class for the observable. However, there is an "Unchecked cast" warning in the *getIdentity* method implementation:

```
    @Override
    public <T extends Observable> T getIdentity()
    {
        return (T) this;
    }
```

How can I improve these solutions?
Which solution is better?
Is there a more elegant way to achieve the desired outcome?

Please note that this example focuses on understanding Java Generics rather than the Observer Pattern itself.

Your insights and suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: I've not digested your full question, because my eye was caught by `Observable <T extends Observable<?>>`: using an unbounded wildcard like the is pretty odd. What are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: @AndyTurner
Thank you for your comment. My objective is to create a generic implementation of the observer pattern. Although the current implementation works, I'm not completely satisfied with it. The question I have posted is specifically about finding a better solution. I have included a second version in my text that removes the unbounded wildcard parameter for the Observable class. However, this version comes with the drawback of an unchecked cast warning in the implementing class.
If you have any suggestions on how to enhance this code, I would greatly appreciate your input.

Comment: AFAICS, you are only using the elements of `observerList` to invoke `observer.update(...)`. As such, these are consumers, and should be bounded by `? super Observable` instead.

Comment: @bhansen You said that you dislike the first solution because **the method getIdentity** and **the usage of a type parameter in the class of the observable**. That does not explain why you dislike these. Both of those bullets are good strategies that have their place, especially in this problem. Why do you dislike them? What problems do they cause you?

Comment: @davidalayachew
Thank you for your comment. In fact, I assumed that doing it that way would be considered poor style, but perhaps my assumption was incorrect.

Comment: @bhansen Well, what about it would be considered poor style? What problems or issues would result by choosing to use the method getIdentity and the usage of a type parameter in the class of the observable?